# Calling Java function from within jQuery slider through JSNI

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, jsni

I have got the main class (say `StockWatcher`) call a JSNI to define a jQuery UI dialog within the body at page-load. The dialog is called within a `JSNI` function. On `onModuleLoad`, I do something like `prepareUI();`. The `prepareUI` JSNI runs as follows:

```
public void native prepareUI() /*-{
  $wnd.jQuery($doc).ready(function($) { 
    message = "<div id = 'message'>Don't do this...</div>
    $(message).appendTo("body");
    $( "#message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close:function() {  this.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::doit()(); },
            autoOpen: true,
            show: {
            effect: "puff",
            duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 500
            }
        });
 });
}-*/;
```

This is followed by the `doit()` function, which is simple enough:

```
public void doit() {
  Window.alert("Foo");
}
```

But, on page-load, even though the dialog appears correctly, and even closes corrrectly on clicking the `Ok` button, the alert doesn't pop up (No error is shown in console). Can anyone tell me how to fix this? The class within which this is done is `StockWatcher` in the package `com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client` (imagine the default GWT `StockWatcher` package hierarchy).

Comment: Same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275087/gwt-calling-instance-method-from-external-javascript (and you should use `$entry` too)

Comment: tried replacing this with you whole class name ?

Comment: Whole class name meaning?

Comment: You mean replacing *this* by `com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher`?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer  :) just going to paste that link.Cheers

Comment: No,first follow the link given by Sir Thomas.

Comment: Okay, trying that. Why do you call him Sir?

Comment: :) :) Learnt/Learning things from him(I mean from his solutions(SO) and articles on google groups) :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25783/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-cupidvogel)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Well, it works. I followed your suggestion on the answer you suggested, and added `var that = this` and used `that.@...`. Also, I changed the jQuery alias to `$$`. You should give an answer so that I can accept it for others' convenience..:)

Comment: I initially wanted to mark it as a duplicate of the other question, but the other guy is struggling to make it work, and SO wants the other question to have an accepted answer. Added an answer here then; with some additional research on jQuery (I don't know a bit about jQuery, this is all from the docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `this`. When the function is called, `this` is not your `StockWatcher` class (it'll be your `#message` element). You have to use `$.proxy` or a simple `var that = this` at the top of your method. It's all about *scoping*.

BTW, you should also wrap your function with `$entry`: it'll make sure a few things go well in GWT: exceptions are routed to the `GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler`, and commands scheduled *via* `Scheduler#scheduleEntry` and `Scheduler#scheduleFinally` are correctly called.

Example using `$.proxy`:

```js
var closeFn = $.proxy($entry(function() {
    this.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::doit()();
  }), this);
$wnd.jQuery($doc).ready(function($) {
  …
  $( "#message" ).dialog({
    …
    close: closeFn,
…
```

Example using `var that = this`:

```js
var that = this;
$wnd.jQuery($doc).ready(function($) {
  …
  $( "#message" ).dialog({
    …
    close: $entry(function() { that.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::doit()(); }),
…
```

Comment: Well, so much awesomeness in one answer!

Comment: Oh, BTW, you can make `closeFn` event simpler, given you're only calling your method: `var closeFn = $.proxy($entry(this.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::doit()), this);`